# Javascript onkeyup event(how to mention Arrow keys in my code)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I'm using javascript onkeyup event,i'm restrict only numbers and backspace and tab button. I need to mention Left right up and down arrow keys in my code... how can i mention in my code... please help

This is my code

```
  function Validatenumber(txt) {
        txt.value = txt.value.replace(/[^0-9\n\r]+/g, '');
    }

 <input type="text" id="mobile" maxlength="11" name="Mobile" data-bind="value: Mobile" onkeyup = "Validatenumber(this)" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code is for checking NUMBERS as input

JS CODE

```
  function checkForOnlyNumbers(e){
     var a = [];
     var k = e.which;
     a.push(0);
     a.push(8);
     a.push(127);
     a.push(46);

     for (i = 48; i < 58; i++)
        a.push(i);

     if (!(a.indexOf(k)>=0))
        e.preventDefault();
   };
```

and in HTML add keypress listener

```
<input type='text' onkeypress='checkForOnlyNumbers(event)' />
```

Comment: your code accepts arrow keys delete keys and everything.....except special characters and letters

Comment: Check the updated code, this works on mozilla too... If you still face any issue please let me know. Thanks :)